# I can't find cloud service in azure publish

Tags: azure, publishing

I did the listed steps in this page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683676.aspx

I downloaded the file and import it, after that I copied the certificate path and upload it under settings/ Management certificates.

then I am trying to use the created subscription to publish the web application, in the cloud service drop down I see no service , although in management portal there is a cloud service created,

Plz help me if I missed up anything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Windows Azure Project, then select Web / Worker Role. (.NET Azure SDK)
PS: In case you already have a project, right-click on roles and add from existing web project.

So, you will publish this azure project to a cloud service.

more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee405487.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't see the Cloud service in Server Explorer

Comment: you must create a new project. Right click on solution (in solution explorer menu) -> add new project. Select Cloud project. If you can't see this option you need to install Azure .NET SDK

Comment: If you already have a cloud project, then you can see Service Configuration and Service Definition File. You will configure instance size / instance number in there. After that. Just import your publish profile (download it from azure management portal) to this Cloud Project and publish it.

Comment: another option: Right click on your cloud project -> Package ...

After that, it will create two files: .cspkg file and .cscfg. Go to azure management portal, select your cloud services then Update production deployment. You will upload this two files and it will publish.

Comment: check this image http://tinypic.com/r/2dcj210/5
I don't have options to deploy from management portal !!!

Comment: @AmirSamir click that "New Production Deployment" and upload this two files that I told you.

Answer (score 0):

Some cloud services can NOT be deployed to through the publish wizard in Visual Studio for a Cloud Service Project. For example, any Service that already has a VM deployed to it, and is an IAAS VM. Any empty Cloud Service or a cloud service that only has PAAS deployments would show up.
Look at the list of cloud services that are available to you in you Server Explorer ->Windows Azure ->Cloud Services.
Is this an empty Cloud Service? If not make an empty one blank one and you should find it in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I can't see any cloud service under Server Explorer ->Windows Azure ->Cloud Services

but I can see the Virtual machine under Server Explorer ->Windows Azure ->Virtual machines.

I am not sure what is the issue or the needed configuration to show the cloud service, waiting your help